# Jquery select rows with specific text in a column in dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatable

I have a datatable with some columns and a dropdown. I need to perform a filter and show only some specific rows that contains the text from the dropdown in a single column (`column[1]`).

Here's my dropdown:

```html
<select class='filter' id="select" data-col="1">
  <option value="val1"> val1 </option>
  <option value="val2"> val2</option>
  <option value="val3"> val3</option>
  <option value="val4"> val4</option>
  <option value="val5"> val5 </option>
  <option value="val6"> val6</option>
  <option value="val7"> val7</option>
  <option value="val8"> val8</option>
  <option value="val9"> val9</option>
  <option value="val10"> val10</option>
</select>
```

The HTML table structure is describe in the JSFiddle above.
If the dropdown is set to `val4`, it should only give the rows containing that value on column (`col[1]`).

Table code:

```html
<table id="datatable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>va1</th>
      <th>test1</th>
      <th>test1</th>
      <th>test1</th>
      <th>test1</th>
      <th>CreatedDate</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>val3</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>2020-20-10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>val4</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>2020-20-08</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>val4</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>2020-20-10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>val4</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>2020-20-10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>val6</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>2020-20-09</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's my js:

```js
$("#select").change(function() {
  var choice = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
  $("table tr").each(function(index) {
    if (index !== 0) {
      $row = $(this);
      var id = $row.find("td.val").text().toUpperCase();
      if (id.indexOf(choice) == -1) {
        $row.hide();
      } else {
        $row.show();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Right now it is not throwing any error, but it is not searching anything. I need to search the lines with the name, not the exact name but even part of it, in the column val.

here's the link to JSFIDDLE (updated): [https://jsfiddle.net/feanor93/vg5eq2ua/8/](https://jsfiddle.net/feanor93/becgq7fL/20/)

EDIT: on my actual page as soon as I click on an element in the dropdown the table becomes empty, like it isn't finding anything, while on JSFIddle it is not working at all

Comment: Show sample rows of your table here if you can.

Comment: I have added the rows and columns code here. Fiddle is more complete

Comment: You're trying to `.find('td.val')` but no `td` element has class `val`. So which particular cell `td`/column are you targetting?

Comment: I need to search in the column named val. How do I search in it?

Comment: That syntax is for class selectors. You want to use `:contains("val")` for that.

Comment: How do I modify the code in my JSFiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/feanor93/becgq7fL/22/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to your answers I managed to find an easy and useful solution. This code works for the whole table, even if there are multiple pages in it, and checks for the occurrence on a single column:

```
$('#select').on('change', function () {
                    table.columns(1).search( this.value ).draw();
                } );

});
```

Remember that columns start from 0, so in this case it is searching on column 2 only got every occurrence of the selected element in the dropdown named "select", regardlress of the case sensitive option.

Answer (score 1):

1. First off, there is no need to skip the first row, as long as you start at the `tbody`.

   - Change your selector to: `table tbody tr`.
2. Next, what is `td.val`? Your table cells, in the code your provided, you don't have any class names defined.

   - Just change the search to `td`.
3. Lastly, you can just call `.toggle` to change the visibility of the row.

**Edit:** I added a reusable jQuery plugin below, along with a pure ES6 version.

```js
const filterRowsContainingText = (table, query) => {
  const isQueryEmpty = query.trim().length === 0;
  table.querySelectorAll('tbody tr').forEach(tr => {
    tr.style.visibility = ([...tr.querySelectorAll('td')].some(td => {
      return td.textContent.toUpperCase() === query.toUpperCase();
    }) || isQueryEmpty) ? 'visible' : 'collapse';
  });
};

$('#datatable').DataTable(); // The only jQuery code...

document.querySelector('#select').addEventListener('change', e => {
  filterRowsContainingText(document.querySelector('#datatable'), e.target.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<p id="date_filter">
  <input type="text" id="datepicker_from" class="form-control date-range-filter" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" placeholder="From:">
  <input type="text" id="datepicker_to" class="form-control date-range-filter" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" placeholder="To:">
  <select class='filter' id="select" data-col="1">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="val1">val1</option>
    <option value="val2">val2</option>
    <option value="val3">val3</option>
    <option value="val4">val4</option>
    <option value="val5">val5</option>
    <option value="val6">val6</option>
    <option value="val7">val7</option>
    <option value="val8">val8</option>
    <option value="val9">val9</option>
    <option value="val10">val10</option>
  </select>
</p>
<table id="datatable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>va1</th>
      <th>test1</th>
      <th>test1</th>
      <th>test1</th>
      <th>test1</th>
      <th>CreatedDate</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>val3</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>2020-20-10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>val4</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>2020-20-08</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>val4</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>2020-20-10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>val4</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>2020-20-10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
      <td>val6</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>2020-20-09</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

### Alternatively...

You could define a reusable jQuery plugin and pass the query to the table. Keep in mind that you have to handle an empty search query.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.filterRowsContainingText = function(query) {
    const isQueryEmpty = query.trim().length === 0;
    this.find('tbody tr').each(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).find('td').map(function() {
        return $(this).text().toUpperCase();
      }).toArray().some(function(text) {
        return text === query;
      }) || isQueryEmpty);
    });
    return this;
  };
})(jQuery)

$('#datatable').DataTable();

$('#select').on('change', function() {
  $('#datatable').filterRowsContainingText($(this).val().toUpperCase());
});
```

Here is how you would do it in pure JavaScript.

```js
const filterRowsContainingText = (table, query) => {
  const isQueryEmpty = query.trim().length === 0;
  table.querySelectorAll('tbody tr').forEach(tr => {
    tr.style.display = ([...tr.querySelectorAll('td')].some(td => {
      return td.textContent.toUpperCase() === query.toUpperCase();
    }) || isQueryEmpty) ? 'block' : 'none';
  });
};

$('#datatable').DataTable();

$('#select').on('change', function() {
  filterRowsContainingText($('#datatable').get(0), $(this).val().toUpperCase());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to ignore case, is as simple as showing all elements which contains desired text and hide the others:

```
$("#select").change(function() {
    var choice = $(this).val();
    $("table td:contains("+choice+")").show();
    $("table td:not(:contains("+choice+"))").hide();
});
```

If you want to ignore case, you just need to remove the `.val` when you try to find `td` elements. `td.val` means to search elements `<td>` tags with class `val`, like `<td class="val">`.

```
$("#select").change(function(){
    var choice = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
    $("table tr").each(function (index) {
      if (index !== 0) {
        $row = $(this);
        var id = $row.find("td").text().toUpperCase();
        if (id.indexOf(choice) == -1) {
          $row.hide();
        }
        else {
          $row.show();
        }
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: @gaetanoM Why did you alter this user's code and add `tbody` to the selector? You should have added a comment letting them know about this potential "fix"...

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl because he was almost there in the solution.....

Comment: @gaetanoM Yeah, but you should have just provided your "better" solution as a separate answer. If your edit went into the edit queue (especially for a new user's response), it would have been denied. Just letting you know that making edits that change the meaning behind someone else's solution could ding you in the future. See: [_"What is the etiquette for modifying posts?
"_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11476/206689)

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I already upvoted for you...... Sorry

Comment: I removed the snippet that someone has added to the answer, as it is not working properly

Comment: @Tamajon thank you, it is working! But I'm experiencing an issue: I need to search for that occurrency only on a single column, the second one, not in every columns. And another thing I noticed: since the table is very long, I splitted the rows using a button that shows only 10-20-50 rows per page, with a page counter on the bottom right to switch pages. That number is never changed, the filter apply only for the page I'm looking at. How can I make it search for every column in the whole datatable, even with the rows in the other pages? Thank you again.
I Have updated my JSFiddle

Answer (score 0):

Since you're likely to have more than one cell returned get the values as an array: `$row.find("td:contains(val)").map((i, td) => td.textContent.trim().toUpperCase()).get();` Then use `Array#some(function)` to test if your choice matches any of the returned value: `id.some(val => val.indexOf(choice) === -1)`.

```
$("#select").change(function() {
    var choice = $(this).val().trim().toUpperCase();
    $("table tr").each(function(index) {
        if (index !== 0) {
            $row = $(this);
            var id = $row.find("td:contains(val)").map((i, td) => td.textContent.trim().toUpperCase()).get();
            if (id.some(val => val.indexOf(choice) === -1)) {
                $row.hide();
            } else {
                $row.show();
            }
        }
    });
})
.change();
```

- Of course, there's a lot of room for improvement.

**DEMO**

```js
    $("#select").change(function() {
        var choice = $(this).val().trim().toUpperCase();
        $("table tr").each(function(index) {
            if (index !== 0) {
                $row = $(this);
                var id = $row.find("td:contains(val)").map((i, td) => td.textContent.trim().toUpperCase()).get();
                if (id.some(val => val.indexOf(choice) === -1)) {
                    $row.hide();
                } else {
                    $row.show();
                }
            }
        });
    })
    .change();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='filter' id="select" data-col="1">
    <option value="val1"> val1 </option>
    <option value="val2"> val2</option>
    <option value="val3"> val3</option>
    <option value="val4"> val4</option>
    <option value="val5"> val5 </option>
    <option value="val6"> val6</option>
    <option value="val7"> val7</option>
    <option value="val8"> val8</option>
    <option value="val9"> val9</option>
    <option value="val10"> val10</option>
  </select>

<table id="datatable">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Id</th>
<th>va1</th>
<th>test1</th>
<th>test1</th>
<th>test1</th>
<th>test1</th>
<th>CreatedDate</th>
</tr>
</thead>


<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Id</td>
<td>val3</td>
<td>test1</td>
<td>test1</td>
<td>test1</td>
<td>test1</td>
<td>2020-20-10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Id</td>
<td>val4</td>
<td>test1</td>
<td>test1</td>
<td>test1</td>
<td>test1</td>
<td>2020-20-08</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Id</td>
<td>val4</td>
<td>test1</td>
<td>test1</td>
<td>test1</td>
<td>test1</td>
<td>2020-20-10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Id</td>
<td>val4</td>
<td>test1</td>
<td>test1</td>
<td>test1</td>
<td>test1</td>
<td>2020-20-10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Id</td>
<td>val6</td>
<td>test1</td>
<td>test1</td>
<td>test1</td>
<td>test1</td>
<td>2020-20-09</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```